# CFString convert to String for kUTTypeImage in Swift 2.0 & XCODE 7

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I got an error convert CFString. Error message is:

> Cannot assign a value of type '[CFString]' to a value of type '[String].

How to fix?

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
picker.allowsEditing = false
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage] //Error Message : Cannot assign a value of type '[CFString]' to a value of type '[String]'
picker.delegate = self
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)//
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the header file:

```
public var mediaTypes: [String]
// default value is an array containing kUTTypeImage.
```

Since the default value is what you want, you can actually just delete that line.

But if you want to keep it, you just need to explicitly cast the type:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer